# DOM object of XML, to HTML

Tags: jquery, html, xml, dom

I have a XML code with a XML table

```
<displayTable>
<tr>
<td> items </td>
<..>
</displayTable>
```

its structured just exactly like a table in HTML but the name of the element is different.
I then parseXML it with jQuery, and get a DOM object.  But now when I'm trying to get the html elements of the tables, but i don't get the HTML table(no errors, I get the items within the tags) when using `.text()` and `.html()`... anyone know why?

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion.
So its similar to this js. I want the HTML code from the XML. So just the A...
At the line&&& it produces "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined" error
    var str = "A";

```
$('#code-analysis').html(str);
console.log(str);

// parse string of XML code
var xmlString = str;
var xml = $.parseXML( xmlString );
$xml = $( xml );


// print to table in console
var displayTable = $xml.find( 'displayTable' ).children;
console.log ( displayTable );


// print table.text() to console, 
// but not in the HTML format 
// just the text within the element
var displayTableText = displayTable.text();
console.log ( displayTableText );              // A


// print table.html() to console
var displayTableHTML = displayTable.html();  // &&&
console.log ( displayTableHTML );
```

Comment: What's the code you're using.  `$.parseXML` *doesn't* return a jQuery object.  You may need to do `$($.parseXML(xml))`.

Comment: you need to show more code. what do you do with jQuery? what do you see on the `console.log()`? what do you expect instead?

Comment: @Rocket Yeah I already did that, thanks though

Comment: @Pavel Veller see the edit xD

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `.children()`, not `.children`. It's a function call in jQuery, not a property. Also, you can pass the children to `.html()` without having to convert them to string (I was getting an error trying to do that).

With that, it's just a matter of adding the table rows to a `<table>` element: http://jsfiddle.net/cRRAM/3/

Comment: Sorry, I might have missed the parenthesis when copy and pasting.hahaha
But it still only produces the text within, without the <tr> and <td> tags. Or do you mean I have to reproduce all those tags again?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean "reproduce the tags for the table"? BUT: the code I linked to had an error too, I'm working on a fix, hold on.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to adjust my code to using .html() like that. Do you know why retrieving code with .html() causes an error? Is  it because .html() only gets code from HTML objects and I was trying to get it from a jQuery object?

Comment: I'm not sure why, maybe because it's coming from XML. I'm curious too, I'll try to look into it and post my findings here.

Comment: Reason found: `.html()` is not available on XML documents (see http://api.jquery.com/html/).